# no such bean definition exception in spring

Tags: java, spring, exception

I am new to the concepts of Spring and Hibernate.
I am using collections in my simple spring program. My idea is to store an author name, address and id into collection. It's a simple spring framework but I am struck with one error.

spring-model.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="book" class="com.vishal.Book">
        <property name="author ">
            <list>
                <ref bean="book1 " />
                <ref bean="book2 " />
                <ref bean="book3 " />    
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="book1" class="com.vishal.Book">
        <property name="name" value="mark twain" />
        <property name="address" value="London" />
        <property name="id" value="230" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="book2" class="com.vishal.Book">
        <property name="name" value="gutav friedman" />
        <property name="address" value="Germany" />
        <property name="id" value="231" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="book3" class="com.vishal.Book">
        <property name="name" value=" Erastothe " />
        <property name="address" value="spain" />
        <property name="id" value="232" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

main class

```
package com.vishal;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Springmain {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "spring-model.xml");
        Book book = (Book) context.getBean("book");
        book.authorName();
    }

}
```

book.java

```
package com.vishal;

import java.util.List;

public class Book {

    private List<Author> author;

    public List<Author> getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(List<Author> author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void authorName() {
        for (Author authors : author)
            System.out.println(authors.getAddress() + authors.getId()
                    + authors.getName());
    }
}
```

author class

```
package com.vishal;

public class Author {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int id;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Following is the error which I a getting

```
Jun 10, 2013 11:29:36 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@161d36b: startup date [Mon Jun 10 11:29:36 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 10, 2013 11:29:36 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-model.xml]
Jun 10, 2013 11:29:37 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b5998f: defining beans [book,book1,book2,book3]; root of factory hierarchy
Jun 10, 2013 11:29:37 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b5998f: defining beans [book,book1,book2,book3]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'book' defined in class path resource [spring-model.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'book1 ' while setting bean property 'author ' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'book1 ' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.vishal.Springmain.main(Springmain.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'book1 ' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: You have a whitespace trailing `author`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Book` class you have a `List<Author>` but in your *spring-model.xml* file you refer to `book1`, `book2` and `book3` as instances of `Book`, not from `Author` probably due for copy/paste process and forgetting the most important step: **adapt what you pasted**.

Just to show an example:

```xml
<bean id="book1" class="com.vishal.Book">
```

It should be

```xml
<bean id="book1" class="com.vishal.Author">
```

Also, you're referring to other beans using

```xml
<ref bean="book1 " />
```

There's a white space in the end that should be trimmed. It should be

```xml
<ref bean="book1" />
```

Similar for other `bookX` references in your *spring-model.xml* file.

Answer (score 3):

There is space in bean references:

whereas actual bean name has no space:

Also as Luiggi suggested Bean definition needs to corrected.

Please check this.

Comment: You are right man, this auto-complete in xml is culprit, adds spaces.